# Get Cookie Volume and set for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, volume, mute

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. What I'm trying to do is find the code for getting the volume to go back to the original state before the user has clicked the mute button.

I already have the mute button and volume slider.

I've heard someone say that to get the old volume, to use var x = document.cookie;
I'm a bit confused as to if I put the var in the mute function or the volumeslider function.

I have these lines of code, too:
document.cookie  = "oldvol=" + volumeslider.value  / 100;
else { ... volumeslider.value = getCookie("oldvol") * 100;

Just confused as to how to set it up to make it function. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I need to set the object reference, add the event listener, and set the javascript.

Comment: So, you should start with some cookie basics. Like maybe at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).  That will tell you how to save data in a cookie and retrieve it again.  What part do you need help with?  Are you having just very basic trouble writing functions in JavaScript at all? Again, at w3schools, learn about [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Comment: `localStorage` might be better/easier than dealing with cookies. [On w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) there is a tutorial on how to set/get objects. In general way easier than cookies.

Comment: This is what I have:

</video>
  
  <div id="video_control_bar">
  
   <button id="playpausebtn"> Play </button>
   <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
   <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span> / <span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
   <button id="mutebtn"> Mute </button>
   <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
   
  </div>
 
 </div>

Comment: For my javascript, I have: function vidmute (){


if(vid.muted){
  vid.muted = false;
  mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
 
 }else {
 
 vid.muted = true;
 mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
 
 
 }

 
}

function setvolume (){

vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;

}

Comment: What I want to do is have the volume slider go down to zero on mute and back to where it was on unmute